# The question on the thm 49.1 in munkres topology.

Tags: general-topology, analysis

[image]

This is the Thm 49.1 of Munkres topology. I have a question on the last part of the picture.
At the last part, Aurthor only consider the case which $\Delta f(x,h)=\frac{|f(x+h)-f(x)|}{h}$, and only consider $\Delta g(x,h)=\frac{|g(x+h)-g(x)|}{h}$,

Now I have a question about this part. If $\Delta f(x,h)=\frac{|f(x+h)-f(x)|}{h}$, then is this decide $\Delta g(x,h)=\frac{|g(x+h)-g(x)|}{h}$?

Or otherwise, we should consider 4 cases to perfect proof.

(i)$\Delta f(x,h)=\frac{|f(x+h)-f(x)|}{h}$,$g(x,h)=\frac{|g(x+h)-g(x)|}{h}$

(ii)$\Delta f(x,h)=\frac{|f(x-h)-f(x)|}{-h}$,$g(x,h)=\frac{|g(x+h)-g(x)|}{h}$

(iii)$\Delta f(x,h)=\frac{|f(x+h)-f(x)|}{h}$,$g(x,h)=\frac{|g(x-h)-g(x)|}{-h}$

(iV)$\Delta f(x,h)=\frac{|f(x-h)-f(x)|}{-h}$.$g(x,h)=\frac{|g(x-h)-g(x)|}{-h}$

Answer (score 1):

Munkres considers $0 \le h  \le 1/2$. In case only one of $x+h$ and $x-h$ belongs to $I$, say $x+h \in I$, then necessarily $\Delta g(x,h)=\frac{|g(x+h)-g(x)|}{h}$. But if both $x+h$ and $x-h$ belong to $I$, we must treat all of your four cases. Munkres assumes $\Delta f(x,h)=\frac{|f(x+h)-f(x)|}{h}$ and says that the other case is similar. But in fact Munkres only treats (i) although he should do it also for (iii).

Answer (score 0):

suppose (iii), and by Munkres, we have

$$\frac{|g(x+h)-g(x)|}{h}>n$$

By the definition of $\Delta g(x,h)$,

$$\Delta g(x,h)=\frac{|g(x-h)-g(x)|}{h}>\frac{|g(x+h)-g(x)|}{h}>n$$
as desired.